# php mysql - non autoincrement primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Is it safe to create manual primary keys (non-autoincremental). I want to use php

`$id = timestamp("now");`

and set that as value of the primary key.

Why ?

Because i'm trying to insert multiple records say 100 in a table with LOAD DATA INFILE but the problem is that tables in my database have relationships and i don't know hot to get the primary key value of parent table and insert it as foreign key in child table.

My idea is to save manual value for primary key and use it in another insert as foreign key.
First, tell me if im safe to use my method, then practical solution with LOAD DATA INFILE would be great. Thanks !

**Edit :** 
As stated in the comments, i think some do not understand the nature of my problem. I use PDO and i know how to get lastInsertId() and set it as foreign key in child table. The problem is i collect big data and i don't insert in a loop or whatsoever. Please understand the problem then try to comment or earn points, be helpful. If my approach is not safe, then give a solution or a reference and explain how would i insert big data in multiple tables with LOAD DATA INFILE while maintaining relationships.

Comment: Using primary keys that have the potential to be the same is **bad practice**. At some point, you will end up losing data.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will help you but [there are functions](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) that return the last auto-incremented ID after an insert query. You may want to use them instead.

Comment: There's always the possibility that two timestamps are the same, even though the chances are very small. It could happen, which you always want to avoid! I think this is an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you're trying to do/achieve?

Comment: I want to use timestamp or current time and set it as a value. How can current time with minutes seconds days months and years on it be same as other time with minutes seconds days months and years...

Comment: Please read my question. Im trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE to insert values in multiple tables with relationships in between. One approach i thought it was using timestamp to manualy create primary keys and insert them in two tables. How can current hour minute second day month year be same again ?

Comment: The problem is 'i don't know hot to get the primary key value of parent table and insert it as foreign key in child table', not 'Is it safe to create manual primary keys (non-autoincremental)'

Comment: @P1nGu1n don't try to be clever, but helpful. I use PDO and i know how to get lastInsertId(). The problem is that i gather large amounts of data and im trying to insert those in a database with LOAD DATA INFILE not within a loop or whatsoever, and maintaining relationships in multiple tables !

Comment: This means you can only insert a max of one new record per second... How about UUIDs?

Comment: How are you generating the files for `LOAD DATA INFILE`? During the generation, how do you determine which records in file A are related to which records in file B? Like deceze said, a good approach would be to generate UUIDs when the files are generated and save them there with the rest of the data.

Comment: @DCodes, thats exactly what i'm trying to achieve. I save my data in a csv file fields terminated by , and lines terminated by PHP_EOL. I'm trying to create a unique id for each record manually.

Comment: Then that's exactly what you should do, look up how to generate UUIDs/GUIDs in PHP and use those as keys.